# Configure entity framework to use char instead of varchar

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

How can I configure an entity framework model to generate a table having columns of type `CHAR(X)` instead of `VARCHAR(X)` or `NVARCHAR(X)`?

Comment: What is the question? How to use `char` parameters instead of `nvarchar`? Or how to generate tables using char instead of nvarchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## To use `CHAR/NCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR/NVARCHAR`

Use the `IsFixedLength` method in addition of `HasMaxLength`.

```
  builder.Property(x => x.MyField).HasMaxLength(10).IsFixedLength();
```

## To use `CHAR/VARCHAR` instead of `NCHAR/NVARCHAR`

You need to call `IsUnicode(false)`

```
  builder.Property(x => x.MyField).IsUnicode(false);
```

Comment: Why force *char* in the first place? This won't have any benefit while querying. It makes sense if EF is used to create the database. In that case though it's probably better to create proper scripts to ensure the correct collations are used and avoid conversion errors